# SVG pattern repeating from set location

Tags: svg

i have an pattern that i repeat in a rectangle. By default it start at the top left of the rectangle and flows across. Instead of starting the first pattern at the top left is it possible to start it from say the middle and work outwards from that point?

Cheers
Luke

Comment: patternTransform="translate(x, y)" where x and y are numbers no good for you?

Comment: Didn't know there was a translate option in there, i'll see if that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can translate a pattern using a patternTransform e.g.

```html
<svg>
  <defs>
  <pattern id="pattern1"
           x="10" y="10" width="20" height="20"
           patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" >

      <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" style="stroke: none; fill: #0000ff" />

  </pattern>
  <pattern id="pattern2"
           x="10" y="10" width="20" height="20"
           patternTransform="translate(2, 5)" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" >

      <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" style="stroke: none; fill: #0000ff" />

  </pattern>
</defs>

<rect x="10" y="10" width="100" height="100"
    style="stroke: #000000; fill: url(#pattern1);" />    

<rect x="140" y="10" width="100" height="100"
    style="stroke: #000000; fill: url(#pattern2);" />    
</svg>
```